# Scrollable TextBlock Sized EXACTLY 2 Lines High

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I need the text to display - at most -2 lines - with no vert scroll visible, then show the  scroll when greater than 2 lines:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="40">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RoadsString}" Style="{StaticResource WrapTextStyle}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

I can experiment with the MaxHeight value until it's looks right - but I'd prefer that it accommodate whatever font is specified and ... precise. Preferably in XAML.

Can I bind MaxHeight to the font size? Or perhaps there a TextBlock property I haven't found.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would a readonly borderless TextBox work for you as a TextBlock?

```
<TextBox MinLines="2" MaxLines="2" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

[MinLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.minlines.aspx) and [MaxLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlines.aspx) would restrict textbox to always have exactly two lines (except if you set Height explicitly - If the Height property is explicitly set on a TextBox, the MaxLines and MinLines property values are ignored).

One problem I see with this approach is that the TextBox's text won't be left aligned with other textblocks (if you have placed them in same column of a grid).

EDIT: Just noticed that you actually want a border for your textblock. For that you can get rid of BorderThickness="0" part.

Comment: Thanks, publicgk, that's PERFECT. I have 2 other TextBlocks in the same grid I'm gong to change to TextBox as well so the user can copy/paste if needed.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simpler solutions (without getting into measuring strings and calculating margins, padding, etc. in a value converter) is to make a hidden (not collapsed) `TextBlock` that only has however many lines you want and bind its `ActualHeight` to the visible `TextBlock`'s `MaxHeight`. The invisible `TextBlock` used as the measure must have its `Visibility` set to `Hidden` so that it is still part of layout calculations even if it isn't shown (`Collapsed` will cause it to disappear altogether).

Here's a demonstration you can throw into a new project to see it work (I use 4 lines to make the scrollbar easier to use).

This part replaces the default `Grid` inside the `Window`:

```xml
<Grid TextElement.FontSize="12">
    <TextBlock Name="limiter"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="100"
               Visibility="Hidden"
               Background="Gray">
    </TextBlock>
    <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=limiter, Path=ActualHeight}"
                  Margin="40,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="LightGray"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock Name="vis" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Name="AddLine"
            Padding="8"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Click="AddLine_Click">Add A Line</Button>
</Grid>
```

In the `Window`'s constructor I add the however many lines I want to the hidden `TextBlock` (you could also use `Run` and `LineBreak` elements in the XAML):

```cs
var limitString = "AgjZ";
limitString = limitString + Environment.NewLine + limitString + Environment.NewLine + limitString + Environment.NewLine + limitString;
limiter.Text = limitString;
```

The `Button`'s `AddLine_Click` handler looks like this, so you can see the effect with different numbers of lines:

```cs
private int counter = 0;
private void AddLine_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
    var newline = string.Empty;
    if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( vis.Text ) )
        newline = Environment.NewLine;
    vis.Text += string.Format( newline + "This is line #{0}.", ++counter );
}
```

Remember that the hidden `TextBlock` needs to be in pretty much the same scope as the one you want to show so that it inherits `FontSize` and other font-related values. If anything is set on the `ScrollViewer` or visible `TextBlock`, it needs to go on the hidden `TextBlock`, too. You could also use binding to make sure the hidden one has the same style as the visible one.